# PySpark UDF crashing at return cloudpickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding) with code() argument 13 must be str, not int as error

Tags: pyspark

### The issue

When running my udf (listed below), an exception gets thrown from a Python worker. The exception being

> File "C:\PATH\SparkInstallation\spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 471, in loads
> return cloudpickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> TypeError: code() argument 13 must be str, not int

I do not know what would cause this error, and it seems like it might be caused by something else than my code.

### The code

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, ArrayType
import re
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as pysparkfunctions

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()

savedTweets = spark.read.csv("testData/")

def getHashtags(string):
    return re.findall(r"#(\w+)", string)

getHashtagsUDF = pysparkfunctions.udf(getHashtags, ArrayType(StringType()))

savedTweets = savedTweets.withColumn("hashtags", getHashtagsUDF(savedTweets['tweet']))

savedTweets.show()
```

Where savedTweets has one column called 'tweet' that contains the text of a tweet. The expected outcome would be a second column that gives an array of strings that lists the used hashtags.

### Example of UDF

Given the input " #a #b #c", outputs ['a', 'b', 'c']

Given the input "  a @b #c", outputs ['c']

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Solved it by downgrading python version to 3.7

Edit: It also works in 3.10.9